# How to read react context/state data inside continuous async loop without restarting loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management, react-state

Node, React, Hooks, Client-side only

I want to have a continuous loop for API with a task queue and delays between each call enforced (for that loop) no matter which component requests for calls come from.

I also decided to make it visual to see progress on calls easier so created as a component.

Here is a simplified example of the problem: the async loop runs outside of new instances of component and I attempted to get the state in 3 ways with loop output in smaller font & button to change state:

1. enclosed `state` (provided from context)
2. passed as parameter ref `st`
3. and even `refState` from useRef(state)

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-einstein-qyq87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1

You can hit add task button and notice the internal to loop task length does not update since it launched. I can also dispatch from within but without the current state, I'm resetting global state. I added dot animation so you can see the loop is alive.

I found a solution that appears hacky so I don't want it to get "fixed" hence looking for a more reasonable solution:

MAYBE SOLUTION: add cloned `useState` that copies state to clone on every state change (with `useEffect`), use setClone inside in callback form to grab state from "previous value". Using clone directly does NOT get the latest state.

```
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(Store);
  const [clone, setClone] = React.useState(state);
  React.useEffect(() => setClone(state), [state]);

  // api loop
  const apiLoop = async () => {
    let haxState;
    setClone(val => {
      haxState = val; // copying value
      return val; // not changing anything
    });
----------
   await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    // loop self
    apiLoop();
  };

  const [isLooping, setLooping] = React.useState(false);
  if (!isLooping) {
    apiLoop(); // start
    setLooping(true); // label started so don't restart
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/late-leftpad-5x2ti?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I was pretty happy to find something compatible with react that will let me read off tasks from (sort of) global state but I wish I could do it with the state object directly instead of involving an additional `useEffect` and entire new `useState` just to clone my state. I'm also not sure if my reducer or context can do something similar to setState(value => b) form to grab the most recent value, it was designed to change value not grab it so makes me nervous.

I am not really interested in any solutions where the loop stops. The client might be pushing 100s of tasks to it that cannot overlap, repeat, or keep being stopped. Assume there cannot be server-side handling of any kind, pure client-side. (not shown is the event on unloading that kills loop if necessary)

Any ideas or is my solution, not an accident and ok to use?

Thank you

---

Update:

Maybe I was overthinking it. I forgot I can use classic js objects linked by reference once, place them outside of component so they do not reinitialize on rerenders, and use them to grab the most recent version of the state

```
import React from "react";
import { Store } from "./state";
import "./styles.css";

// value placed outside component where it's not remade
const last = {};

export const App = () => {
  // global state
  const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(Store);
  // update reference for last.state object without updating reference for last object
  // so last still points to same const above but last.state points to newest state
  last.state = state;

  let a = 0; // little counter

  // api loop
  const apiLoop = async () => {
    if (window.output)
      window.output.innerHTML = `
      apiLoop:\n
      last.state.tasks: ${last.state.tasks.length}\n
      ${".".repeat((a++ % 3) + 1)}
    `;

    // 1000ms api delay for rate limit
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    // loop self
    apiLoop();
  };

  // initialize loop
  const [isLooping, setLooping] = React.useState(false);
  if (!isLooping) {
    apiLoop(); // start
    setLooping(true); // label started so don't restart
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-dijkstra-27p36?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I guess I answered my own question. Sorry. I'll leave this up in case there are more elegant solutions. This is much cleaner without superfluous react hooks, so will do for now. code sandbox works :)